# Kotlin incompatibility problem when adding ads/billing to older Android app

Tags: android, kotlin, incompatibility

I'm working on a legacy Android project which is working fine on the latest Android API 33 (Gradle version 8).

I get a problem when I'm trying to add ads/billing by including the following imports in build.gradle(:app):

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:6.1.0"
```

The full build.gradle(:app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://github.com/joytunes/USB-MIDI-Driver/raw/master/MIDIDriver/snapshots'
    }
    mavenCentral()
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ditek.midisheetmusic"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/library-core_release.kotlin_module']
        }
    }

    namespace 'com.midisheetmusic'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.5.0'
    implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:6.1.0"

    
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'jp.kshoji:midi-driver:0.1.5:@aar'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

    // For the navigation drawer
    implementation "com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:7.0.0-rc01"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3"
}
```

The full build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.21"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.3.41'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8"
}
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
```

When I'm trying to run the project, I get the following error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
e: C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5f906034cba9b66675b64ced85218cdc/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-java-1.0.0-beta05-api.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/68d94d5209b3f92a883bbf7bbae93a8b/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-1.0.0-beta05-api.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/5f906034cba9b66675b64ced85218cdc/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-java-1.0.0-beta05-api.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices-java_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a330e8ddb3730f3d01f15559f5ef2975/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/afa79d8fd554748751d607d4d94ea74c/transformed/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b87af3d7ac94e764394ad63bacdb1719/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (12, 28): Class 'androidx.annotation.ColorInt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a330e8ddb3730f3d01f15559f5ef2975/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/androidx/annotation/ColorInt.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (13, 28): Class 'androidx.annotation.ColorRes' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a330e8ddb3730f3d01f15559f5ef2975/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/androidx/annotation/ColorRes.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (14, 28): Class 'androidx.annotation.LayoutRes' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a330e8ddb3730f3d01f15559f5ef2975/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/androidx/annotation/LayoutRes.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (35, 10): Class 'androidx.annotation.LayoutRes' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/68d94d5209b3f92a883bbf7bbae93a8b/transformed/jetified-ads-adservices-1.0.0-beta05-api.jar!/META-INF/ads-adservices_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a330e8ddb3730f3d01f15559f5ef2975/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/androidx/annotation/LayoutRes.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (49, 13): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (50, 17): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (51, 42): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (53, 28): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (54, 28): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (55, 28): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (61, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (66, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (71, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (95, 23): Unresolved reference: let
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (96, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (97, 173): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a330e8ddb3730f3d01f15559f5ef2975/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/annotation.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (99, 175): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (108, 25): Class 'androidx.annotation.ColorInt' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a330e8ddb3730f3d01f15559f5ef2975/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/androidx/annotation/ColorInt.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (109, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/afa79d8fd554748751d607d4d94ea74c/transformed/jetified-kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.1.jar!/META-INF/kotlinx-coroutines-core.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (113, 28): Class 'androidx.annotation.ColorRes' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/a330e8ddb3730f3d01f15559f5ef2975/transformed/jetified-annotation-jvm-1.6.0.jar!/androidx/annotation/ColorRes.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (114, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (119, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/b87af3d7ac94e764394ad63bacdb1719/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-common-1.8.22.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (124, 14): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (129, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (134, 15): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (138, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (141, 27): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (142, 27): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (143, 27): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (144, 27): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (150, 21): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (151, 39): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (163, 22): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (164, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (165, 26): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (167, 26): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (171, 9): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class
e: C:\Users\Z\Downloads\MidiSheetMusic-Android-master\app\src\main\java\com\midisheetmusic\drawerItems\AbstractExpandableSwitchDrawerItem.kt: (183, 19): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
The class is loaded from C:/Users/Z/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/858b8e47903f8052faca9a32fc80081f/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.22.jar!/kotlin/Unit.class

0 problems were found storing the configuration cache.

See the complete report at file:///C:/Users/Z/Downloads/MidiSheetMusic-Android-master/build/reports/configuration-cache/cbngny7vmeq10ks1esuvg880b/6qvoavwkygexco9htps4mvsua/configuration-cache-report.html
```

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Slightly downgrading the billing/ad libraries fixed this.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:6.0.0'
```